# DeepSearch - Return Only The Index Number

Tags: python

I'm using [DeepSearch](https://deepdiff.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dsearch.html) to find an item and that works. What I want is to only return the index ID for `['members']`. In this case the ID is `[1]`. Any ideas on how to do this?

Any help would be appreciated, I'm still learning Python so trying to work through the problems.

code:

```
from deepdiff import grep
obj = response.json()
item = ".rep"
ds = obj | grep(item, verbose_level=2)
print(ds)
```

Returns:

`matched_values': {"root['data'][1]['members'][0]['address']"}}`

Could this be filtered by using regex? \D would filter to 1 and 0. How would I remove 0 and only leave 1?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the following code:

```
import requests
from deepdiff import grep
import re

response = s.get(url)
obj = response.json()
item = ".rep"
ds = obj | grep(item)
print(ds) # {'matched_values': {"root['data'][8]['members'][0]['address']"}}
aa = re.search(r"\d", str(ds))
print(aa) # <re.Match object; span=(34, 35), match='8'>
if aa is not None:
    bb = re.findall(r'(\d)', str(ds))
    print(bb) # ['8', '0']
    if len(bb) == 3: # The list may be three characters total
        bb.pop(2) # The third character is not needed
        print(bb)
        bb = ''.join(str(i) for i in bb[:2]) # convert the list to a string
        print(bb)
    else:
        bb = re.search(r'(\d)', str(ds)) # find only the first int as that's all that's needed
        print(format(bb.group(0))) # 8
else:
    print('no matches found')
```